# Using variables with session (express-session) - loggedin & username works, but not the others

Tags: node.js, express

Simple login authorization code:

```
app.post('/auth', function(request, response) { 
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                request.session.bsa = 'randomstringasdfasdf';
                response.redirect('/account');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

The problem is with request.session.bsa (without it, no error, and with it, there's an error "ReferenceError: request is not defined"). I want it to save some string which will be used in the future. However:

-request.session.loggedin works

-request.session.username works

But request.session.bsa doesn't work.

How can I save a string in the session which is going to be used in the future, just like the use of username?

Comment: Which express-session store are you using?  What are your express-session, initialization options set to?  Depending upon store and init options, you may have to call `request.session.save()` to save new properties and wait for that to complete before calling `response.redirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem wasn't with the session variable, but with the string type input of the variable. Later on, this was used as the integer and not the string, so I just had to provide an integer value to the session variable.